# Visual Studio reciprocal reference

Tags: visual-studio, reference, project, projects-and-solutions

Is that a problem if a solution contains many projects and there are some cases when:

1. Project A references Project B
2. Project B references Project A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because the compiler won't know which one to compile first to satisfy the dependency.  Consider pulling the common pieces out into Project C and having the two projects both depend on that.